# ruby regex not working to remove class name from sql

Tags: ruby, regex

I have:

```
BEFORE Gsub sql :::: 

    SELECT record_type.* FROM record_type WHERE (name = 'Registrars')


    sql = sql.gsub(/SELECT\s+[^\(][A-Z]+\./mi,"SELECT ")


AFTER GSUB SQL :::: 

    SELECT record_type.* FROM record_type WHERE (name = 'Registrars')
```

The desired result is to remove the "record_type." from the  statement:

So it should be :

```
    SELECT * FROM record_type WHERE (name = 'Registrars')
```

After the regex is run.

I didn't write this, it's in the asf-soap-adaptor gem. Can someone tell me why it doesn't work, and how to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it should be written like this...

```
sql = sql.gsub(/SELECT\s+[^\(][A-Z_]+\./mi,"SELECT ")
```

... as the code in the question won't match if the field name contains `_` (underscore) symbol. I suppose that's why this code is in gem: it *can* work in some conditions (i.e., with underscoreless field names).

Still, I admit I don't understand why exactly this replacement should be done - and shouldn't it include `0-9` check as well (as, for example, `'record_id1'` field still won't be matched - and replaced - by the character class in the regular expression; you may have to either expand it, like `[0-9A-Z_]`, or just replace completely with `\w`).

Comment: @Joelio if you are happy with this answer, it might be a good idea to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

so your before and after gsubs are the same?  I can't tell you why it doesn't work if you dont tell me your expected result.  Also for help with interpreting ruby regular expressions check out rubular.com

Comment: I did, but the people edited, my question into making it confusing

Comment: @Joelio You can edit it back, but it'd better if you describe the problem. )

Comment: thanks, I just added clarity, my debug print statements were inline before, I think that was more clear.